# Google Calendar web interface generates recurring series with UNTIL date preceding start time

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

**Steps to Reproduce**:

1. Use Google Calendar's web interface to create a new recurring event. Then fetch the event data via the API. Here's the JSON snippet for reference:

```json
{
  "summary": "test recur move last",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-10-09T10:00:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-10-09T10:30:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20231011T205959Z"
  ]
}
```

2. Move the last occurrence of the event series from October 11, 2023, to October 14, 2023. Choose the "This and following" option.

[image]

Google Calendar will then split the original series into two separate ones:

First series:

```json
{
  "summary": "test recur move last",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-10-09T10:00:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-10-09T10:30:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20231010T205959Z"
  ]
}
```

Second series:

```json
{
  "summary": "test recur move last",
  "start": {
    "dateTime": "2023-10-14T10:00:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
  },
  "end": {
    "dateTime": "2023-10-14T10:30:00+03:00",
    "timeZone": "Europe/Kiev"
  },
  "recurrence": [
    "RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;UNTIL=20231011T205959Z"
  ]
}
```

**Issue**:
The second series starts on October 14, 2023, but has an "UNTIL" date of October 11, 2023. Logically, this series shouldn't have any occurrences. However, Google Calendar still shows one occurrence on October 14, 2023.

**Question**:
Is this behavior intended or is it a bug?

Comment: What you're seeing is expected behavior. The one showing up as October 11 in your JSON is the original date set in the reoccurrence, and the feature of the events wasn't designed to be moved around. However, it still gives us flexibility in doing so. If an event has been moved, the only thing that would change now are the start and end dates. Notice that Google Calendar now treats the event that's been moved as a regular event. If you delete the original reoccurrence you created, the one that was moved won't be included.

Comment: If you wish to have this checked out, you can always take a shot at submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new), as that's the best way to tell Google about these kinds of things.

Comment: @Saddles Thanks for your answer. Couple more questions if you don't mind.

> Google Calendar now treats the event that's been moved as a regular event.

By regular do you mean a single non-recurring event? Because from the API perspective, both of them now have `recurrence` and look like two different recurring masters now.

Comment: @Saddles And one more question. Previously I thought that the occurrences of a recurring series were placed in calendar according to the RRULE in a range from startTime to UNTIL. But this is definitely not the case here. I'm working on a solution for synchronizing events from Google Calendar to another system, and I need understand how to handle such cases. Would it be correct to say, that Google Calendar always places an occurrence at recurring master's startTime, no matter what the RRULE defines?

Comment: `By regular do you mean a single non-recurring event?` Yes. Try doing this: Create another test event, let's say from October 7 to October 11. Then, move the October 9 event to October 14 and select `This and following events.` Essentially, that should move all the events. However, it deletes October 10th and 11th, which can be considered a feature request if I'm not mistaken. As for `Would it be correct to say, that Google Calendar always places an occurrence at recurring master's startTime, no matter what the RRULE defines?` You are correct.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped out! I'll post my initial comment as an answer so that other community members who stumble upon this question may know this information. Feel free to accept the answer and upvote it as well.

Answer (score 1):

What you're seeing is expected behavior. The one showing up as October 11 in your JSON is the original date set in the reoccurrence, and the feature of the events wasn't designed to be moved around. However, it still gives us flexibility in doing so. If an event has been moved, the only thing that would change now are the start and end dates. Notice that Google Calendar now treats the event that's been moved as a regular event. If you delete the original reoccurrence you created, the one that was moved won't be included.

If you wish to have this checked out, you can always take a shot at submitting a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new), as that's the best way to tell Google about these kinds of things.